# Nextjs Context Api not maintaining state on page change

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

**Describe the bug**

When changing pages using router.push Context Api Provider seems to be remounting and losing held state despite being initialized

**To Reproduce**

context.tsx

```js
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'

export const CatStateContext = React.createContext(null);

const Context = ({ children }) => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

    const appProvider = {
        count,
        setCount
    }

  return (
    <CatStateContext.Provider value={appProvider}>
        {children}
    </CatStateContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default Context
```

PageA.tsx

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { CatStateContext } from '../components/context'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Link from 'next/link'

const PageA = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
    const {count, setCount} = useContext(CatStateContext)

  return (
    <>
     <button onClick={()=>setCount((prev)=>prev+1)}>
      +1
    </button>
     <Link href="/pageA/pageB">
     <button>
      to pageB
     </button>
    </Link>
    </>
  )
}

export default PageA
```

PageB

```js
import React, {useContext} from 'react'
import { CatStateContext } from '../components/context'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const PageB = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { count } = useContext(CatStateContext)

  return (
    <>
    <div>{count}</div>
    </>
  )
}

export default PageB
```

context file
[image]

```js
import React from 'react'
import PageA from '../../../components/pageA'
import Context from '../../../components/context'

const Index = () => {
  return (
    <Context>
      <PageA />
    </Context>
  )
}

export default Index
```

**Expected behavior**
After updating context within a page the context should be maintained across all page routes.

Comment: Where do you wrap the `Context` component?

Comment: pageA 's index and pageB 's index file

Comment: try to wrap context in _app.js file

Comment: just to add what @HamudeShahin has caught already: now you are initializing context inside of route. Route changes - different component renders - context Provider is recreated, alongside with data in it

Comment: Is there a way for me to preserve my context state when switching routes?